# Iframe audio fade on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, vimeo

Some of you may know those cool audio fades on scroll. i am trying to use that method on a "vimeo iframe". my intention is to let the sound of a video fade scrolling down the page and letting it get louder back again scrolling up. to be honest i am a super newbie at js and not even an advanced user of html and css so i am sorry if i am asking for too much if its not possible at all please tell me.

this is what im working with: (credits to http://codepen.io/envira/pen/AuGKh)
its basicaly a vimeo clip and the script effect for an audio fade

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>soundtest</title>
<link href="soundcss - Kopie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var events=["abort","canplay","canplaythrough","durationchange","emptied","ended",
            "error","loadeddata","loadedmetadata","loadstart","pause","play","playing",
            "progress","ratechange","readystatechange","seeked","seeking","stalled",
            "suspend","timeupdate","volumechange","waiting"]

            $(document).ready(function() {
    var audioElm = $('#scrollaudio').get(0);
    audioElm.play();

    var height = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        audioElm.volume = 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / height;
        console.log(audioElm.volume);
    });
   });
</script>
<style>

.article1 {
    height:800px;
    background:#124A70;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.article2 {
    height: 900px;
    background: #E04006;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

p {
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #111;
}

@charset "utf-8";


.vimeoFrame {width:638px; height:358px; overflow:hidden; margin:0 auto;} .vimeoFrame .vimeoXtra {margin-top:-100px;}
.vimeo {display:block; width:638px; height:358px; margin:0 auto;} 
.vimeoXtra {display:block; width:638px; height:558px; margin:0 auto;}

#wrapper{
    height:358px;
    width:638px;
    background-color:
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="article1"><p> Scroll Down</p>
<div id=wrapper">
<div class="vimeoFrame"> <iframe class="vimeoXtra" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/98417189?autoplay=1&loop=1" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
</div>

    <audio loop id="scrollaudio" src="Material/8_Mile_Battle_Instrumental.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="article2">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am sorry if i am acting stupid and scrub-ish but i hope you can help me

kindest regards

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine - just mp3 file in your example is not available for direct download. Try other mp3: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPMQmq

```
<div class="article1"><p> Scroll Down</p>
    <audio loop id="scrollaudio" src="http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

P.S. Use the browser console to debug the application - a great idea!

Comment: i think you didnt understand my question. i want to do what the audio does with the video actually. but thanks anyway